# how to create 1 gb csv file with random data using python

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
import random
from faker import Faker
from datetime import datetime


l=Faker('en_GB') 
f=open("test.csv","r")
k=csv.reader(f)

g=open("1.csv","w")
w=csv.writer(g)
w.writerow(('id','name','address','college','company','dob','age'))
for i in range(20000):

    w.writerow((i+1,l.name(),l.address(),random.choice(['psg','sona','amirta','anna university']),random.choice(['CTS','INFY','HTC']),(random.randrange(1950,1995,1),random.randrange(1,13,1),random.randrange(1,32,1)),random.choice(range(0,100))))
f.close()
```

when i increase the range to 10000000 
terminal kills the process...... please can anyone help me . how can i generate  larger csv file with random data .

Comment: What do you mean the terminal kills the process? It is automatically being killed or you are killing it?

Comment: automatically killed by  kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import random
from faker import Faker
from datetime import datetime


l=Faker('en_GB') 
f=open("test.csv","r")
k=csv.reader(f)

g=open("1.csv","a")
w=csv.writer(g)
w.writerow(('id','name','address','college','company','dob','age'))
for i in range(1000000):

    w.writerow((i+1,l.name(),l.address(),random.choice(['psg','sona','amirta','anna university']),random.choice(['CTS','INFY','HTC']),(random.randrange(1950,1995,1),random.randrange(1,13,1),random.randrange(1,32,1)),random.choice(range(0,100))))
f.close()
```

append option solved my problem.

```
g=open("1.csv","a")
```

after i use this its taking time to create the csv file of 1.6 gb.with random data

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2, `range` will create a list and may therefore have memory troubles with large input values.

If that's the case, use `xrange` instead. It has fixed memory requirements regardless of the input value.

The Python 3 `range` is more akin to the Python 2 `xrange` so it shouldn't be a problem there.